# Javascript - best way to parse custom tags

Tags: javascript, ajax, parsing

I wrote an API that returns the following

```
 <location><lat>41.47033705</lat><lon>-81.93612862</lon></location>
 <location><lat>41.470320224762</lat><lon>-81.9364535808563</lon></location>
 <location><lat>41.4704650640488</lat><lon>-81.9449239969254</lon></location>
 <location><lat>41.4780235290527</lat><lon>-81.8454140424728</lon></location>
 <location><lat>41.48597253</lat><lon>-81.82579113</lon></location>
```

I have an AJAX call that gets this and now I need to use it in my JavaScript.

Ultimately I would like and 2d `Array [lat,lon]`

What is the least amount of code to do this?

Comment: A regular expression.

Comment: This is why I didn't try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: @abc123 for this example assume that this is just JavaScript and Ajax.

Comment: @AMR Your XML is well defined, so it's safe to perform a regex.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I suck at regex. Can you post an example? I know how to do it in C#. I would just create a matches object and run something simple but how the hell do you do it in javascript?

Comment: @AMR: *This is why I didn't try [a regular expression]* This is why you should try it http://stackoverflow.com/a/7564061/1081234

Comment: @AMR regex answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your AJAX call via XmlHttmlRequest and get responseXML. Then you can parse your data via XmlDocument method and properties.

You can even run [Xpath queries](http://richardpianka.com/2011/01/cross-browser-xpath/) on the result to select exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the response is valid XML, you can use `getElementsByTagName` and push to an array:

```
var arr = [];
for (var location in response.getElementsByTagName('location'))
{
    arr.push([
        parseFloat(location.getElementsByTagName('lat')[0]), 
        parseFloat(location.getElementsByTagName('lon')[0])
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This is all custom tags that I have created. It will be standard and never very so will this still work?

Comment: Without a root tag it isn't valid XML.

Comment: @AMR -- yes, that's fine.  Javascript can work using the DOM on a schemaless XML document returned via Ajax.

Comment: @McGarnagle btw you just blew my mind addings things to array with no size....

Answer (score 1):

Just use JQuery's selector engine to parse your code.

Wrap your elements in a `<div id="data"> ... </data>` for easy selection and you can do the following:

```
var _locations = $('#data').find('location');
var my_data = [];

$.each(_locations, function(index, loc) {
    var _lat = $(loc).find('lat');
    var _lon = $(loc).find('lon');

    my_data.push([_lat.text(), _lon.text()]);
})

// my_data will contain a 2D array of your lat, lon
```

GoodLuck

-Kiru

Comment: user states no jquery...

Answer (score 1):

### [Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/zW1tP3)

**Regex**

```
<lat>([^<]+)<\/lat><lon>([^<]+)<\/lon>
```

using `g` (*global*) flag

***Description***

```
<lat> Literal <lat>
1st Capturing group ([^<]+) 
    Negated char class [^<] 1 to infinite times [greedy] matches any character except:
        < The character <
<\/lat><lon> Literal </lat><lon>
2nd Capturing group ([^<]+) 
    Negated char class [^<] 1 to infinite times [greedy] matches any character except:
        < The character <
<\/lon> Literal </lon>

g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

***Visualization***

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

### Taking the above to solve your specific issue

**DEMO [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdjjN/)**

***JS***

```js
var text = " <location><lat>41.47033705</lat><lon>-81.93612862</lon></location><location><lat>41.470320224762</lat><lon>-81.9364535808563</lon></location><location><lat>41.4704650640488</lat><lon>-81.9449239969254</lon></location><location><lat>41.4780235290527</lat><lon>-81.8454140424728</lon></location><location><lat>41.48597253</lat><lon>-81.82579113</lon></location>";

var myregexp = /<lat>([^<]+)<\/lat><lon>([^<]+)<\/lon>/g;
var results = new Array();
var match = myregexp.exec(text);
while (match != null) {
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i = 1; i < match.length; i++) {
        result.push(match[i]);
    }
    results.push(result);
    match = myregexp.exec(text);
}

console.log(results);
```

*the variable `results` contains a 2d array [lat, lon]*